# Edit selected rows manually in SQL Server

Tags: sql, sql-server-2008

I have a database in which some editing operations have to be done manually on some rows. I have the SQL Server Management Studio Express. In SSMS, to edit the rows, normally the option is:

`Select DB > Table > Right Click > Edit top 200 rows`

But, the problem here is that I only have to edit some selected rows. I am able to retrieve these selected rows by the following query:

```
/****** Script for SelectTopNRows command from SSMS  ******/
SELECT *
  FROM [test].[dbo].[Sheet1] WHERE Item1 IS NULL OR Item2 IS NULL
```

Now, I have to perform some edit operations (moving some data from some columns to others) which can't be performed with a query because of no single observable pattern for editting. So, the question remains, how can I get these rows in edit mode to do my task?

Answer (score 48, accepted):

Click edit rows on the table and then open the sql tab of that query and add your predicate there. And that's how you can edit filtered records.

[image]

Comment: I am not able to find the `SQL tab` that you mentioned to actually filter these `editable records`. Unlike typical queries, which have a SQL console appearing above the results in SQL server, I do not see the same console for typing in SQL for edittable records Screenshot: http://i.imgur.com/jv6ro.pngords

Answer (score 12):

As you said, go for

```
Select DB > Table > Right Click > Edit top 200 rows
```

Now the window opens with the top 200 query and the results editable.

Now change the query to the one with your where clause and hit F5

Comment: Where do I change the query when the top 200 edittable records appear? Unlike typical queries, which have a SQL console appearing above the results in SQL server, I do not see the same console for typing in SQL for edittable records Screenshot: i.imgur.com/jv6ro.pngords

Comment: or go to Query Designer -> Pane ->SQL

Answer (score 1):

After you have your 200 rows displayed for editing, you can also click on the "SQL" icon which will now be available above the Object Explorer.  This is another way to have the SQL displayed which you can now edit as needed in order to change the desired rows.

Answer (score 1):

To expand on other answers, once you open the SQL pane and have edited the SQL, you can click Ctrl-R or click the "Execute SQL" button to actually execute the SQL [image]

Answer (score 1):

Using LinqPad (https://www.linqpad.net/) you can direct edit previous run select query. It also has many other features like running Linq or C# codes.