# How to edit MULTIPLE rows/data entries in SQL Server Management Studio

Tags: sql, sql-server, edit, ssms

I want to update/edit multiple rows in a database using SQL Server Management Studio. I know you can edit one entry using solutions provided [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4543478/how-to-edit-data-in-result-grid-in-sql-server-management-studio), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1535469/how-to-quickly-edit-values-in-table-in-sql-server-management-studio) or [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9552877/edit-selected-rows-manually-in-sql-server) using Edit Top(200) function. But I want to edit >100 entries so this is not an adequate solution. I am using SSMS 2012.

**EDIT:**

As an simplified example we can look at the following situation: 
I have a database of peoples names and their height. But many of the heights are wrong or not updated. So I want to update their heights. This update includes a lot of people and it is tedious to update one by one using the solution I linked too. I have to updated values stored in an Excel file.

I am not sure of how to attack this problem, but is seeking a way that I can copy paste the updated values directly into the tables or do this indirectly using some sql statement.

Comment: See updated version of my question.

Comment: My question has been put on hold due to claims that I seek debugging help without providing enough information about the code/undesired behavior etc. This is not the case and its hard for me to see why people would think this. My problem is that I did not know how to start solving or coding a solution, thus I have no code to provide. I'll try to make this more clear.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

If you select ***Edit Top 200 Rows*** first, you can then modify your query to return 250 rows.

In order to do this you need to click on ***Show SQL Pane*** button, in the top left corner, just below the ***New Query*** button.

In your query window change *200* to *250* and hit Ctrl + R to refresh.

However, if you really need to update this number of rows, you should probably use raw SQL and write proper UPDATE statements.

**EDIT:**

In the situation you described, I normally create individual **UPDATE** statements within Excel and then copy the whole lot to execute in SQL:

[image: Excel file]

Comment: I am new to SSMS, so how can I write a proper Update statement? The values I want to update with is stored in an Excel file.

Answer (score 1):

You can actually paste content to and from excel directly into the ssms editable datagrid. And you can easily change the number of rows available for edit in the ssms "tools > options > Sql Server object explorer" section to return the 250 rows you would need to edit.

As jerry said though it might be easier to write t-sql statements, there is a quick primer on sql update statements over at [w3schools](http://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_update.asp)

EDIT: based on the discussion in the comments, here is how to update a table based on the values from another table. I've left the original answer above

Provided you have access to a table @myTable with the correct values, and this table has two columns (Name, height), you can do an update FROM

```
UPDATE t
SET Height = temp.Height
FROM TableIWantToUpdate t
JOIN @myTable temp ON temp.Name = t.Name
```

EDIT2: as requested, here is a breakdown of the code

```
UPDATE t
```

means update the table aliased as "t" in the FROM + JOIN clauses

```
SET Height = temp.Height
```

Here we are setting the column Height of the tabled aliased "t" to the value of the column Height in the table aliased temp. The "t" alias is implicit because its been specified in the UPDATE statement

```
JOIN @myTable temp on temp.Name = t.Name
```

Basically we are creating a list of records which we want to update, saying that each record in table "t" that matches a record in table "temp" will be updated accordingly.

As to the values in @myTable aliased "temp" in the sample, you could probably get it with some SQL like this

```
DECLARE @myTable TABLE (name varchar, height properNumericType)
INSERT INTO @myTable (name, height)
SELECT 'John', 5.6
UNION
SELECT 'Mary', 5.4
UNION
...
```

Comment: Thanks for the link. This will probably work, but I can not think of an easy way to use this. For my example in my question with name/height database, How can I update multiple heights with one t-sql statement? it seems like I can only update one height corresponding to one name at the time.

Comment: Either you write multiple statement and filter the record you update with a WHERE clause on the name, or you dig into the CASE WHEN construct to act as your WHERE clause

Comment: Thanks for the link. This will probably work, but I can not think of an easy way to use this. For my example in my question with name/height database, How can I update multiple heights with one t-sql statement? it seems like I can only update one height corresponding to one name at the time. 
I was thinking it was possible to order the search and then updating all the rows by specifying an array of height values? or writing an name/height array to update? similar to inserting data e.g. 
INSERT INTO db(names,height) 
VALUES  (Jon,6.1), (Eve,5.6),.....

Comment: Ok. So it is not possible to put this into some kind of loop?

Comment: You could use a WHILE loop but I fail to see how it would be easier than simply using the edit table option in the object explorer to copy your up to date data from excel

Comment: To copy the data from excel I have to do one at the time, so it would be very slow. If it is possible to write something like the following it would be great

declare name = (jon, eve,....)

declare height = (6.1,5.6,...)
declare i = 0

While i< name.count
  UPDATE db
  SET HEIGHT=height[i]
  Where NAME=name[i]
  i++
End

Comment: I've updated my answer with an edit that would probably do what you are looking for using an UPDATE FROM instead of a loop which is I think the proper way to do in t-sql

Comment: Could you please elaborate a bit on what the code is doing. 
the @myTable I can just create as a temporary table using INSERT INTO and VALUES. And what is "t", just a dummy variable?

Comment: Thank you for an elegant solution. When I put "AS" to define the alias your statement made sense.