# Update single column in table

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008

I have a Table and I need to update a single column with a new set of quantities, which I have from an Excel Spreadsheet. I already have the Rows I require, but cannot figure out how to update multiple rows at once.

I have tried going to **Edit Top 200 Rows** and modified the SQL there to select the rows I require, but unfortunately you cannot paste down a column.

Any Ideas?

Comment: Is the new rows you're updating varies in quantity?

Comment: Yes it does between 0..20

Comment: I don't think there is a way to do it like you want to do. You have to write an UPDATE...SET for each row you want to update. Or if you've inserted the quantity and a sort of id in a table you could write a cursor.

Comment: Have you seen this trick("after EDIT"): http://stackoverflow.com/a/28321960/284240 ?

Comment: Might not be the best way but i'll take it, Thank you :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I always add columns to write an update or insert text between data columns like dat:
[image]

Then I copy this data to sql managment studio and replace tab '       ' to empty char '' and run queries.

[image]

If the data doesn't match to my table straight from excel i create #TMP table and fill data to it and then operate to data in tmp table in sql.

Answer (score 0):

If you want to update it without wrinting every single update-statement, you'll need a column in your excel that you can uniquely match to a column in the sql table.

I had to do this too a few days ago and I imported the excel sheet into a temporary table (rightclick on Database -> Tasks -> Import Data..) and wrote an update query with a join:

```
UPDATE t
    SET t.columnToUpdate = temp.newValue
FROM TableToUpdate AS t
INNER JOIN temporaryTable AS temp
    ON t.Id = temp.Id
```